# get a list of all our private repos

Tags: github, github-api

I want to get a list of all private repositories in our organisation github.  I tried -

```
curl -u user:pw -X GET  https://api.github.com/orgs/xxx/repos?per_page=100 >> list.txt
```

I figure out that the **per_page**  MAX value is 100 , how can I get all our repos into one file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a bash script that loops over each page until the last page reached is empty.

The filter can be done with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) JSON parser to filter private repository, you can also exclude forked repo or anything you want.

Note that I'm using a [personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) for the authentication (to get private repo) :

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# change those vars :
GITHUB_ORG=docker
GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN=12345666799897950400303332323
OUTPUT_FILE=repo_list.json

loop=0
index=1
TMP_FILE=tmpfile.txt
PER_PAGE=100

rm -f $TMP_FILE
echo "[]" > $OUTPUT_FILE

while [ "$loop" -ne 1 ]
do

    data=`curl -s "https://api.github.com/orgs/$GITHUB_ORG/repos?access_token=$GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN&page=$index&per_page=$PER_PAGE"`
    
    check_error=`echo "$data"  | jq 'type!="array"'`

    if [ "$check_error" == "true" ]; then
        echo "access token is invalid"
    exit 1
    fi

    filtered=`echo "$data" | jq '[ .[] | select(.private == true) ]'`

    if [ "$filtered" == "[]" ]; then
        loop=1
    else
        echo "$filtered" > $TMP_FILE
        concat=`jq -s add $TMP_FILE $OUTPUT_FILE`
        echo "$concat" > $OUTPUT_FILE
        size=`jq '. | length' $OUTPUT_FILE`
        echo "computed $index page - fetched total repo size of : $size"
        index=$((index+1))
    fi
done
```

If want to have only an array of repository URL instead of the whole JSON object, replace :

```bash
jq '[ .[] | select(.private == true)  ]'
```

with :

```bash
jq '[ .[] | select(.private == true)  | .html_url ]'
```

Answer (score 1):

### Github CLI

This is now pretty easy to do via the GH CLI which takes care of all the auth stuff for you after you login.

```
gh repo list <username> --private
```

### Manual

You'll need to [create a personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token), and then you can filter with `type=private`

**Unless you have more than 100 repos, you can just do this**:

```
https://api.github.com/orgs/<org>/repos?per_page=100&type=private&access_token=<token>
```

#### For more than 100 Repos

If you need to traverse more than 100 repos, you'll have to use some additional scripting.

Here's a sample in vanilla JS you can paste into your browser console

```js
let orgName = 'YOUR_ORG_NAME'
let access_token = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'

let baseUrl = `https://api.github.com/orgs/${orgName}/repos`
let params = {
    type: 'private',
    page: 1,
    per_page: 10,
    access_token
}

let repos = [], json = []

do {
    let queryString = new URLSearchParams(params).toString()
    let url = `${baseUrl}?${queryString}`

    let resp = await fetch(url)
    json = await resp.json()
    
    repos.push(...json)

    params.page++

} while (json.length == params.per_page)

console.log(repos)
```

#### Further Reading

- [How to clone all repos (including private repos) from GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70916780/1366033)
- [GH CLI - Repo List](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_list)
- [API - List organization repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-organization-repositories)
- [API - Pagination](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#pagination)

Answer (score 0):

GitHub has an article in their API Guide called [Traversing with Pagination](https://developer.github.com/guides/traversing-with-pagination/) that covers the basics of pagination but also how to [write a small script to gather your data](https://developer.github.com/guides/traversing-with-pagination/#consuming-the-information).